# Showing cumulative load by road segment using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, road

The picture shows the forest roads where wood transport is carried out by trucks. From polygons, logs (wood) are collected near roads and then transported.

How do I show or sum cumulatively  collected the total load by parts of roads using QGIS?

This is necessary so that I can see which section of the road will  be damaged soon. Therefore, it could suggest which part of the road will be reconstructed. Units are in tonnes (t).

In any part of road I can automatically store loads, but I do not know how to sum loads like on picture shown below and put the new value in road segment, automatically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the arrows represent collection points, where load will be added?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I can make point layer with sum loads by ID of roads, but problem is how to copy to road layer? I used plugin "Attribute transfer" but doesnot work. Every road have ID, and point layer also have field with exact road ID. I can only join, by hand, road table with the same ID with in point layer and in that case loads will join to roads. I'm sorry, I'm too complicated.

Comment: Interesting question... how are your segments defined? (In other words, how do they look in the attribute table? Each segment is assigned to one row?)

Comment: Every road segment are splitted with other roads, for this kind of calculation and have unique ID.

Comment: Like rivers. Strahler order

Comment: Aah, something like ("river"=1, "Strahler_order"=2). Then a segment can be looked up by ("road_id" field ==1, "segment_id" field ==2)?

Comment: I added my model builder

Comment: @Kazuhito, how to do that? What is next?

Comment: How to sum values?

Comment: Hi @nagib Sorry, I thought you meant you've already figured out by showing the model builder. For me, to work further I need to know each attribute tables, which would tell us how we link segment id and road id. Or, are you using these terms interchangeably? I mean, one segment is equal to one road?

Comment: I think it's difficult to make the solution automatically. The problem is: Every road has its own ID. The road must be made up of segments, (a part between crossroad). How to summarise values ​​cumulatively, and how to know in which direction should be aggregated.

Comment: @nagib I agree with you, that it is the key to find solution for this. If road_id and segment_id are stored in a layer (or a table), they can be looked up each other. If not, you might need to create a new table by a spatial join.